# Custom room Socket.io NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, socket.io

I am making an application with sockets and the need arises to broadcast information, but only to people who are inside a room.

This is my code from the `server.ts`

```
// Dependencies
import express from 'express'
import http from 'http'
import socket from 'socket.io';
import {connect, disconnect, orderChanged} from './sockets/socket';
import {config} from 'dotenv';

config ();

// Main class
export default class server {

    _private static instance: server
    public app: express.Application
    public port: number
    http: http.Server private
    public io: socket.Server

    // Initialize variables and methods
    // Singleton pattern implementation
    private constructor () {

        this.app = express ()
        this.port = Number (process.env.SRV_PORT)
        this.http = new http.Server (this.app)
         this.io = new socket.Server (this.http, {
            cors: {
                origin: true,
                credentials: true
            }
        })
        this.listenSockets ();
    }

    // Return the instance running Singleton pattern
    public static get instance () {
        returns this._instance || (this._instance = new Server ())
    }

    // Method to start the server
    start (callback: any) {
        this.http.listen (this.port, callback)
    }

    private listenSockets (): void {
        console.log ('Listening Sockets');

        this.io.on ('connection', client => {
            console.log ('Connected to room', client.rooms, '-', client.id);
            // User disconnected
            disconnect (client);
            connect (client);
        });
    }
}
```

Since node starts, an instance is created in DP Singleton and the socket listener is launched
When an operation happens in the database, anywhere in the app, I send it to call and send information to the front-end which is correctly received by the front-end and does what it has to do. Example `url / edit-products`

```
import server from '../core/server';

// Socket broadcast, new information
const __id = String (req.headers.id);
const updatedData = await getNewData (__id);
Server.instance.io.emit ('data changed', updatedData);
```

The problem is that this information is sent indiscriminately to all users connected to the socket. Now, I have a unique ID that brings multiple users together in a MongoDB model. You could use that ID to broadcast only to users with that ID. There is a logic that implies that if the user connects from Mexico, add it to an Array of people in MongoDB, otherwise it will add it to another MongoDB document, then they are two different IDs.
I would love the room to be that ID.

I saw that I could use the socket's `join ()` method, but that function derives from the connected client, not from the server itself. I try to issue the information like this

```
// Socket broadcast, new information
const __id = String (req.headers.id);
const updatedData = await getNewData (__id);
Server.instance.io.in (updatedData._id) .emit ('data changed', updatedData);
```

But at no point did I set up that "ROOM". When the user login, he could add it but I don't know how to create a custom room, he tried something like this

```
const user = await UserModel.find (_data);
Server.instance.io.join (user.channel._id);
```

But that function within io does not exist.

It exists this way, but it doesn't work for me

```
Server.instance.io.on ('user-join', (socket: Socket) => {
   console.log (plug);
   socket.join (uuid);
});
Server.instance.io.emit ('user join');
```

What could I do?

Answer (score 1):

`.join()` is a method on an individual socket.  That's how you use it as `socket.join(roomName)`.  When the first user joins a room, the room is created automatically and other users can also join it.  When the last user leaves the room, the room is removed automatically from the server.  So, you join a user's socket to a room - you don't join something to the server.

---

Similarly, when you tried this:

```
Server.instance.io.on ('user-join', (socket: Socket) => {
   console.log (plug);
   socket.join (uuid);
});
```

That doesn't work because you don't listen for incoming messages from a socket on the server (except for the `connection` message - which introduces the socket object).  You listen for incoming client messages on a socket itself:

```
Server.instance.io.on ('connection', (socket: Socket) => {
    socket.on('user-join', () => {
        // you will have to find the room name that goes with this socket
        socket.join(someRoomName);
    });
});
```

---

Also, note that this code:

```
private listenSockets (): void {
    console.log ('Listening Sockets');

    this.io.on ('connection', client => {
        console.log ('Connected to room', client.rooms, '-', client.id);
        // User disconnected
        disconnect (client);
        connect (client);
    });
}
```

looks problematic.  Why would you disconnect a client when they connect?  You don't show those functions `disconnect()` and `connect()` so it's unclear what they actually do - I would guess they keep track of connected clients somehow.  If you're just trying to clean up any state that might have been previously left hanging, then you should be doing something like this:

```
private listenSockets (): void {
    console.log ('Listening Sockets');

    this.io.on ('connection', client => {
        console.log ('Connected to room', client.rooms, '-', client.id);
        client.on('disconnect', () => {
            // User disconnected
            disconnect(client);
        });

        // user connected now
        connect(client);
    });
}
```

You don't have to worry about inaccurate housekeeping on whether a socket is connected or not.  You will always get a `disconnect` event for a socket when it disconnects.  This is for two reasons.  For a browser window that closes or a page that the user navigates away from, the browser cleans up all objects associated with that page, including the open socket.io connection.  This will always close the socket and cause a `disconnect` event.  Second, socket.io uses `ping` and `pong` messages to regularly check if an existing connection is still working.  If it's not, it will get disconnected.  The client may or may not retry to open a new connection depending upon the circumstance.  But, any disfunctional connection (one that isn't respond to `ping` messages) will get closed by the server and a `disconnect` event will occur for that too.  So, those two circumstances make sure that a `disconnect` event always happens.

> `Server.instance.io.emit ('data changed', updatedData);`  The problem is that this information is sent indiscriminately to all users connected to the socket.

This sends to all users connected to your server and is how it was designed.

To send to a single socket, you would use:

```
 socket.emit(...);
```

where `socket` is what you're code calls `client`, the object you get from the `connection` event.

To send to all sockets who have joined a room, you would use:

```
 io.in(roomName).emit(...)
```

where `io` is the socket.io server instance.

And, there are many, many more variations of `.emit()` depending upon exactly what you're trying to send to.

> Now, I have a unique ID that brings multiple users together in a MongoDB model. You could use that ID to broadcast only to users with that ID. There is a logic that implies that if the user connects from Mexico, add it to an Array of people in MongoDB, otherwise it will add it to another MongoDB document, then they are two different IDs. I would love the room to be that ID.

I don't completely follow what you're trying to do, but it seems like inside your `connect(client)` function, you could just call `client.join(uniqueIDForMultipleUsers)` and that would create a room with this uniqueID and add this client to that room.  In the future, you can send to everyone in that room with `io.in(uniqueIDForMultipleUsers).emit(...)`.

> But at no point did I set up that "ROOM". When the user login, he could add it but I don't know how to create a custom room, he tried something like this

You don't create rooms manually.  You just use `socket.join(roomName)` and the socket.io infrastructure automatically creates the room if it doesn't already exist.  Similarly when the last socket in a room either leaves the room or disconnects, the room is automatically removed.  So you just don't have to manage the room creation or deletion yourself.  In fact, a room object is not something you ever deal with directly - it's a housekeeping item inside of the socket.io server that contains a list of sockets that are currently in the room.  A socket can be in as many rooms as it wants to be.  You use these on the server:

```
socket.join(roomName);     // add a client's socket to a room
socket.leave(roomName);    // remove a client's socket from a room
io.in(roomName).emit(...); // broadcast a message to every socket in a room
```

What is sometimes a bit confusing about the above logic is that `socket.join()` and `socket.leave()` are socket methods, but they actually modify a data structure in the server (where the list of rooms/sockets are kept).  For whatever reason, that's just how they chose to originally design the API.  Logically, it's more like `io.join(socket, roomName)` since it's modifying something on the server.  But, since the socket knows the server object it's part of, they can leave that off and just do `socket.join(roomName)`.